# Evaluate integral of $\langle xz^2,x^2y-z^3,2xy+y^2z\rangle$ with divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

> Q. Evaluate by Gauss divergence theorem
> $$\iint_S xz^2\,dy\,dz + \left(x^2y-z^3\right)\,dz\,dx + \left(2xy+y^2z\right)\,dx\,dy$$
> where $S$ is the surface bounded by $z=0$ and $z=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$.

I was not able to understand this question properly and when I solved this question I got the answer  (2/3)π(a^5). Is this answer correct?
In this question, I solve like this

```
∫∫∫ divF dv
div F =(x^2+y^2+z^2)
∫∫∫(x^2+y^2+z^2) dzdydx
a^2∫∫∫1 dzdydx from limit z=0 to z=(a^2-x^2-y^2)
               from limit y=-(a^2-x^2) to y=(a^2-x^2)        
                    limit x=-a to x=a
```

In this way, I got (2/3)π(a^5) as the answer.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. It's very hard to read

Comment: I can hardly read this. But you seem to be making the mistake of saying that the divergence is constant throughout the region. It is not. It is only constant on one piece of the boundary of the region. One last comment. You want to be working in spherical coordinates when you actually do the integral.

Comment: Thank you for replying..Actually I 'm getting divergence= (x^2+ y^2+z^2)  which I take as a^2.. I don't know how to proceed further..Can you solve it?

Comment: I've spiffed up your question a bit with MathJax; consult the [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for everything else. Next time, please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Did you read my comment? The divergence is NOT $a^2$.

Comment: Yes I read your comment ..thanks for replying..okay..I got divergence as div= (x^2+y^2+z^2)..now how to proceed..

Comment: I'd convert everything to spherical coordinates. Simplifies the expressions with no radicals.

Comment: Can you explain it here? What is your answer?

Comment: The answer is that we expect *you* to integrate your divergence over half of the ball with radius $a\,.$

Comment: Can you show all steps here?

Answer (score 2):

The integral in your post is over a closed volume bounded by half a sphere of radius $a$. By divergence theorem,
$$\begin{aligned}
\oint_{S}\langle xz^2,x^2y-z^3,2xy+y^2z\rangle\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf S&=\iiint_V\text{div}\langle xz^2,x^2y-z^3,2xy+y^2z\rangle \mathrm dV\\
&=\iiint_V(z^2+ x^2+y^2)\mathrm dV\\
&=\iiint_V r^2dV\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^a r^2r^2\sin\theta\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\Phi\\
&=2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^a r^4\sin\theta\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta\\
&=2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\mathrm d\theta\int_0^a r^4\mathrm dr\\
&=2\pi\left[-\cos\theta\right]_0^{\pi/2}\left[\frac{r^5}{5}\right]_0^a=\frac{2\pi}{5}a^5
\end{aligned}
$$
Notice how the divergence is $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\neq a^2$ because you need to integrate over $r\in[0,a]$. If not what you'd be doing is integrating over a surface and not a volume, and thus, divergence theorem wouldn't hold.

Comment: On youtube..I got answer as π/5 a^5..I don't know which one is correct..

Comment: @AnishBangia This answer here is crystal clear. If you think it is incorrect you should clarify why exactly. We have no idea what youtube videos you are watching. Don't even want to know them.

Comment: $$\int _{-a}^{+a}\int _{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\int _0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dzdydx=\frac{2 \pi}{5}a^5$$
Same result.

Comment: @KurtG. We are here to solve problems..okay....I'm not here to show you videos..even if you ask about videos..then also I will not show you..because you are a rude guy..I am nice to everyone here..you should be nice too..don't spread negativity here..

Comment: @AnishBangia that was not my intention but I stand by my statement that it is not helpful to claim that some youtube video got $\pi /5 a^5\,.$ You have received an answer with two upvotes an that is what we should work on if necessary.